# Unable to get material spinner working in android

Tags: android, spinner

I imported a custom material library [Material by Rey](https://github.com/rey5137/material) for my Android project to use a spinner. I have made all the required changes but still, I get an error in my `setAdapter` function

"*Cannot resolve method setPrompt*"

The line of code throwing this error is:

```
spinner.setPrompt("Choose "+Utils.capsAllWords(names));
```

Earlier I used the inbuilt Android spinner widget and the setPrompt() method worked fine. What changes can I make to get around this?

The xml for the widget is-

```
<com.rey.material.widget.Spinner
android:id="@+id/spin1"
style="@style/MyStyle"/>
```

In the activity I have imported `com.rey.material.widget.Spinner` and declared -

```
Spinner sp1;
sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin1);
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no setPrompt() option available in the library

try

```
spinner.setPromptText("Choose "+Utils.capsAllWords(names));
```

**Update**
they didn't exposed the method in the library. You can customise suit your purpose

```
<com.rey.material.widget.Spinner
android:id="@+id/spin1"
android:prompt="@string/message"
style="@style/MyStyle"/>
```

[Check this](https://github.com/rey5137/material/blob/master/material/src/main/java/com/rey/material/widget/Spinner.java#L1254)

Comment: I get the same error as above even after using this.

Comment: Can you paste sample code for Activity/Fragment with XML here